# How can I wrap a heading to two lines and center it?

Tags: html, css, styles, center, html-heading

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Reliable, efficient delivery Powered by Technology</h1>
```

What I want:-

[image]

I tried adding width but then it pushes the heading to the left. How can i achieve this multi-line heading in center.

Comment: So what are you doing to break the line or limit width? Show your attempt, please. Don't just ask for solutions.

Comment: I told you I added width:50%;

Comment: I wanted you to _show_ us how that doesn't work. I think it does.

Comment: If you don’t know in advance where you want the line break to be but you want a sort of balanced heading, so the two rows are of roughly the same length then see the answer involving JS [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630381/text-in-a-div-splitting-in-middle-when-it-word-wraps/67631534#67631534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to add `<br>` - [The Line Break element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).

Or you may do something like this, if you prefer css way https://codepen.io/fromaline/pen/WNpEgXR

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Reliable, efficient delivery <br> Powered by Technology</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this-

```css
#smallheader{
font-size: 50px;
margin-right: 50%;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="smallheader">This is my text that should be on the next line.</div>
```

You can just change the `margin-right: your amount;`

Comment: Fixed margins are not a very modern way to do things like this. It'll only work properly for one screen size.

Comment: Don't tell us down here. Update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You claim that using width doesn't work, but it sure does (along with a standard centering mechanism):

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Reliable, efficient delivery Powered by Technology</h1>
```

This isn't a good approach, though, since it depends on font and container sizes. Better to just break the line explicitly:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Reliable, efficient delivery<br>Powered by Technology</h1>
```